# Trocar valores de uma div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

Tenho um combo quando ocorre o evento `onchange` ele realiza uma consulta no banco de dados com o valor selecionado e insere em uma `div` os valores, o problema é que quando aplico `$('.minhaDiv').html(resultado)` ele me retorna apenas o último dado, tentei com `append` e ele repete várias os dados abaixo dos consultados anteriormente, o que eu precisaria seria que o mesmo sobreposse com todos os dados os valores anteriormente dispostos na tela.

Como eu poderia fazer isto? Alguma solução?

um exemplo do meu código:

```
$("#dados_solicitacao").on('change','#caminho', function change(){
   var selected = $(this).val();
   var url = urlprojeto+"/minhaUrl.php";
            var data = 'referencia='+selected+'';
            var data = get_contents(url, data);
            var aDados  = data.dados;
            var cDados  = aDados.length;
            for( s=0; s<cDados; s++ )
                {

                    var status      = aDados[s].cad_ativo;
                    var referencia  = aDados[s].cad_referencia;
                    var txt= 'ativo:'+status;
                    txt+= ' minha referencia:'+referencia;
                    $(".div_selected").html(txt);
                }
});
```

[image: O que tenho na tela, e gostaria que fosse sempre trocado ao mudar o valor selecionado no combo]

O que tenho na tela, e gostaria que fosse sempre trocado ao mudar o valor selecionado no combo.

Por serem dados diferentes é necessário que sejam substituídos, pois o meu combo serve como um filtro, onde neste combo navego por minhas "pastas" (tópicos do meu site).

Comment: o correto não seria você colocar `$(".div_selected").html(txt);` fora do bloco do `for`?

Comment: já fiz isto e continua me retornando apenas a ultima interação do `for`

Comment: Se possivel poste como é o seu data. O que está imprimindo e o que deveria imprimir. Vai ajudar muito.

Comment: Da maneira que você está fazendo, o conteúdo da div será substituído toda vez que entrar no loop. A função `html` sobrescreve todo o html pelo novo. Você tem que usar o `append` ou `prepend` para fazer isso, quanto ao problema que relatou, acho que seja com seus dados.

Comment: mas como eu poderia fazer isto de outra forma, pois sei que o html troca os valores, e dentro do for ele trocará toda vez que passar pelo loop

Comment: Marcos, podes explicar melhor o HTML e o que queres fazer? tens um select e quantos elementos devem receber o que está no `txt`? Estás a re-declarar as variáveis dentro do `for` porquê: é porque deve ter valores diferentes e não concatenar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta isso,

```
$("#dados_solicitacao").on('change','#caminho', function change(){
   var selected = $(this).val();
   var url = urlprojeto+"/minhaUrl.php";
            var data = 'referencia='+selected+'';
            var data = get_contents(url, data);
            var aDados  = data.dados;
            var cDados  = aDados.length;
            var txt = '';
            for( s=0; s<cDados; s++ )
                {

                    var status      = aDados[s].cad_ativo;
                    var referencia  = aDados[s].cad_referencia;
                    txt+= 'ativo:'+status;
                    txt+= ' minha referencia:'+referencia;

                }
              $(".div_selected").html(txt);
});
```

Veja que vc estava declarando a variável txt dentro do for, agora o valor do txt vai sofrer um append.

Veja se isso resolve seu problema.

Comment: Agradeço a ajuda, havia me esquecido deste detalhe.

Comment: Precisando de ajuda, da um grito!! Abracos

Comment: @RBoschini, você sabe que essa `function change() {...}` poderia ser anônima: `function() {...}`, pois quem faz a tratativa do change é o `.on('change', ...)`

Comment: essa funcao é um eventListener, ele escuta o evento change do controle, você pode atribuir ela a uma variavel e utiliza-la em mais de 1 lugar, mas tornar anonima da forma que vc perguntou vai dar erro.